# Letters in Atom were hard to read after Ubuntu update(18.04)

Tags: atom-editor, ubuntu-18.04

[image]

After Ubuntu upgrade(18.04), my atom editor has changed like the attached picture, which is quite hard to read.
Especially, 'ImportError' looks like 'ImpprtError.

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: These kinds of questions should be posted on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely a problem with FreeType, there are several reports on the [Atom forum](https://discuss.atom.io/search?q=freetype). Try if updating Atom and/or FreeType solves the issue.

Comment: thank you! I've found the same problem and I solved it! (removed and installed again)